# Issue with graphics card memory detection

Tags: c++, gpu, windows, nvapi, vram

I want to detect video memory using `Nvidia API` called `NvAPI`. The problem is that `dedicatedVideoMemory` always displays 0, but it should display 4096 MB.

**Code:**

```
NvAPI_Status result;
result = NvAPI_Initialize();

if (result != NVAPI_OK) {
    NvAPI_ShortString string;
    NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(result, string);
    printf("NVAPI NvAPI_Initialize: %s\n", string);
}

NvU32 cnt;
NvPhysicalGpuHandle phys;
result = NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs(&phys, &cnt);

if (result != NVAPI_OK) {
    NvAPI_ShortString string;
    NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(result, string);
    printf("NVAPI NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs: %s\n", string);
}

NV_DISPLAY_DRIVER_MEMORY_INFO nvidiaDisplayDriverMemory;
NvAPI_GPU_GetMemoryInfo(phys, &nvidiaDisplayDriverMemory);

qDebug() << nvidiaDisplayDriverMemory.dedicatedVideoMemory;
NvAPI_Unload();
```

**Screenshot (NVIDIA Control Panel):**

**[image: Screenshot (NVIDIA Control Panel):]**

**Questions:**

1. How to fix it?
2. How to get proper graphics memory detection on AMD/Intel?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Update:**

```
 NvAPI_ShortString ver;
 NvAPI_GetInterfaceVersionString(ver);
 printf("NVAPI Version: %s\n", ver);

 NvAPI_ShortString name;
 NvAPI_GPU_GetFullName(phys, name);

 if (result != NVAPI_OK) {
     NvAPI_ShortString string;
     NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(result, string);
     printf("NVAPI NvAPI_GPU_GetFullName: %s\n", string); // emit signal - error
 }

    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
```

Now when I add to check version and graphics card name it displays `nvidiaDisplayDriverMemory.dedicatedVideoMemory` as 4096, but only in `Qt` debug mode, when I get to release mode, it displays 0. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__gpu.html#gaf838839f5aca4bd6cdb60fc743ae8ef4) the first parameter is assumed to be of type `NvPhysicalGpuHandle[NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS]`.  Hence if the value of `cnt` is greater than 1 after the call then you've probably got undefined behaviour.

Comment: "Each structure contains a version field which the caller must initialize" from NvAPI Concepts

Comment: @stark

I have checked version: qDebug() << nvidiaDisplayDriverMemory.version;
**Output:** 1402088528

Comment: @G.M.

And have checked:
    `NvU32 cnt;
    NvPhysicalGpuHandle phys;
    result = NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs(&phys, &cnt);

    qDebug() << cnt;
    qDebug() << result;`

**Output:**
    1
    0